# Is there a way to ask some nginx server its connection limit per ip?

Tags: c#, nginx, download

Let's say I am using multiple connections to download one file from an nginx server. Most of the time its limited to like 2 connections. Is there a way to ask the server how many it is allowing? Or do i have to trial and error to find it by myself

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [robots.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt). Perhaps the property "Crawl-delay" may help you if the site specifies that.

Typically you don't want to expose too much information about the technical setup and configuration of your server to the public for security reasons. Of course hiding such information is not gonna prevent persistent adversaries from attacking your server but at least it's gonna make it harder for the script kiddies. But for this reason I have my doubts that NGINX exposes a public API with such information.